# How do I show a table's Has Many relationship on frontend?

Tags: laravel, voyager

Using Laravel + Voyager, I have a "Has Many" relationship:

Course hasMany Teachers.

In backend all is fine, but if I try to get the information in the frontend, I only get the value in table, not the relation, so the output goes something like:

```
0   
id  1
teachers_id null
name    "Math"

1   
id  2
teachers_id null
name "English"
```

Current code in web routing:

```
Route::get('/course', function () {
    $co= App\Course::all();
    return $co;
});
```

How can I get the correct output?

```
teachers_id Xav, Titus
```

Comment: What are you getting as incorrect output?  Also your output does not appear to be in your sample input.

Comment: If relations between models is well made, it should be `$co = App\Course::with('teachers')->get();`

Comment: @Tpojka, thanks, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so like @Tpojka commented you can start by eager loading the relationship when you are initializing the course likeso `$co = App\Course::with('teachers')->get();` after which you do not need to make another unnecessary call to your database for the teachers of that course. You can get a collection of all the teachers of that course by simply calling `$teachers = $co->teachers;` here $teachers is now a laravel collection you can simply loop through it on the client side and display the information about the teachers you want to display. I hope this helps.

Good luck and happy coding. :)

Comment: Thanks, with the answer also checked out a little bit on eager loading.